# optional multi-value dropdowns/parameters in report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012

I have an SSRS report with 3 dropdowns.

- **1st drop down is for doctorDepartment and is multi-value**
- **2nd is for insurancePolicy and is multi-value**
- **3rd is a list of doctors and is single value only**

The 3rd drop down get's it data from a dataset with the query below.

The two parameters, @specialityId and @insurancePolicy are controlled by the 1st two drop downs respectively(doctorDepartment & insurancePolicy).

The problem is, I need the user to be able to selectively choose a value from either drop down or both.

But the way it works now, is that a value from both is REQUIRED in order to display the data in the 3rd drop down...meaning the 3rd drop down is only populuated with data until the user chooses a value from both the 1st and 2nd drop down.

Is there a way to tell SSRS that the user only needs to select a value from 1 or the other or both but not require both?

***I tried allowing null values for the 1st two parameters but SSRS will not allow you to set that option of the parameter allows multi-values.***

Thanks!

```
SELECT ml.doctorID, doctorDisplayName 
FROM doctorList ml
   INNER JOIN doctorDepartment mc ON ml.doctorID = mc.doctorID
WHERE (mc.specialityId IN (@specialityId)
     OR ml.insurancePolicy IN (@insurancePolicy))
ORDER BY doctorDisplayName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with default values:

1. Add an extra label/value pair to the first two parameter lists; this value can be a space `' '`, -1, a word like `'Default'`, etc.
2. Set default values for both to these new values
3. Update your `WHERE` clause to allow one or more selected parameters:

   ```
   WHERE mc.specialityId IN (@specialityId) AND 'Default' IN (@insurancePolicy)  --first param selected
     OR 'Default' IN (@specialityId) AND ml.insurancePolicy IN (@insurancePolicy)  --second param selected
     OR mc.specialityId IN (@specialityId) AND ml.insurancePolicy IN (@insurancePolicy)  --both selected
   ```